# Google Sheets Filter Aggregate Sheet after combing several sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to combine several sheets in google sheets and then apply a filter on the resulting combined sheet.

I have sheets named `jan` , `feb`, etc. I want to combine them into a sheet called `agg`, and then filter a particular column in the `agg` sheet according to several criteria.

I tried this but it doesn't work:

> =filter({filter({{jan!A1:E500};{feb!A1:E500}},{{jan!A1:A500};{feb!A1:A500}}<>"")}, {agg!B1:B32="gym"})

The first filter works, but the second one gives this error:
`No matches found in filter evaluation`

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:
Here is a the example in question:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lUx8z2PHAcsd0md_ozFVX6E7c4NG050d_jYQUVwi3Fw/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Please share a copy of your sheet, to make it easier for us to help you.  Here is a guide:  https://support.google.com/docs/thread/3808684?hl=en

Comment: The sheet is no longer accessible, can you please share it again?

Comment: @JoseVasquez It's Okay, the other person answered, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use:

```
=FILTER({jan!A:E; feb!A:E}, {jan!A:A; feb!A:A}<>"", {jan!B:B; feb!B:B}="gym")
```

or:

```
=QUERY({jan!A:E; feb!A:E}, "where Col1 is not null and Col2 = 'gym'")
```

or shorter:

```
=QUERY({jan!A:E; feb!A:E}, "where Col2 = 'gym'")
```